# Eclipse 2021-12: Hidden code sections - Looking collapsed without any way to expand

Tags: eclipse

In my Java files I have frequently issues like the following example:

[image]

[image]

Eclipse is hiding lines and there is no way to expand them.
My first assumption was that the line endings might be inconsistent (mixed Unix/Windows line endings), so I changed them to Windows line endings with Notepad++, but this did not solve the problem.
How could I fix this problem?

Comment: So, you talking about the Java editor, not about text editors in general, right? Which Eclipse version is that (see _Eclipse > About Eclipse IDE_)? Are the lines hidden or the line numbers incorrect? Does this always happen before and/or after a folding section?

Comment: Yes I have only noticed it in the Java-Editor. My Eclipse version is 2021-12 (4.22.0). the line numbers are correct. Because when I re-open the same file I can see again all lines that were hidden before. It happens between folding sections, which are separated by one blank line. The hidden part in this example contained many functions that were also separated by one blank line. For unknown reason they were collapsed all together without a + to expand them again.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-12 outdated, four releases behind. Please upgrade. Can this be reproduced with the current Eclipse without installing any additional plugins?